# Is 'what' a pronoun or a conjunction?

Tags: pronouns, conjunctions, syntactic-analysis, simile

In the sentences below, is `what` and `as` pronouns or conjunctions? And how do you parse the sentences?

> Facebook is to Sunday morning what karaoke is to Saturday night.
>
> Afghanistan is to the United States as Afghanistan was to the Soviet Union.

Comment: Ok, the what is not really wrong. It could be said, but it's not good in writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sentences are examples of similes. From [Literary Devices](https://literarydevices.net/simile/):

> A simile is a figure of speech that makes a comparison, showing similarities between two different things. Unlike a metaphor, a simile draws resemblance with the help of the words “like” or “as.” Therefore, it is a direct comparison.

"As" and "what" are linking words, also known as connecting words, that establishes the similarity between the two things being compared. "As" is an adverb and "what" is a relative pronoun referring to an abstract noun.

The first sentence is talking about two ways of socializing and having fun. Objectively, they're really different from each other. Looking at Facebook is something you do quietly at home by yourself. Doing karaoke makes a lot of noise and usually takes place in a crowded public place. However, the speaker is saying one activity is just as fun as the other within the specific contexts assigned to each (on Sunday morning/on Saturday night). The speaker is asserting that they produce the same outcome, despite being so different.

The second sentence is comparing the similarity between *the relationship the Soviet Union had to Afghanistan* (the Soviet War in Afghanistan) and *the relationship the United States now has with Afghanistan* (the U.S. War in Afghanistan). See this short overview: https://www.brookings.edu/articles/comparing-the-u-s-and-soviet-experiences-in-afghanistan/.

Comment: The use of what in the OP's sentence is incorrect, though. X is to Y as A is to B.

Comment: @Lambie Good point! I will edit

Comment: @Lambie, would this be correct: "What X is to Y, A is to B"?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. But more elegant is without the what.

Comment: Emily, 'what' sounds perfectly fine to me. What do you think @Lambie means by 'incorrect'?

Comment: @Mitch, I think he thought that the verb clauses were being compared, and "what" is fine since what's really being compared is an abstract noun (how something is/a state)